# Question Password reset token in Laravel Breeze Inertia React

Tags: reactjs, laravel, inertiajs

I have a problem to use password reset view which demanding an token to create the view in laravel breeze combine with inertiajs and reactjs.

my question is :
Q1. Where is the token generated? or where do i retrieve the token?

```
//route
Route::get('reset-password/{token}', [NewPasswordController::class, 'create'])
            ->name('password.reset');
//controller
public function create(Request $request)
{
    return Inertia::render('Auth/ResetPassword', [
        'email' => $request->email,
        'token' => $request->route('token'),
    ]);
}
```

as you can see this route demanding a token to create the view but i dont know how to generate the token. and i cant see any page access this route so there is no example about this.

Q2. How do i pass the token to controller

```
<Link method="get" href={route('password.reset')} data={{ token: token }} as="button">
        Reset
</Link>
```

im planing to do like code above which i can click from user data grid based on user id so only admin can reset your password. or any better idea to implement this?.

thankyou in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you installed **breeze/laravel** fresh installation you can simply generate the token using:

```
$token = $request->user()->createToken($request->token_name);

return ['token' => $token->plainTextToken];
```

What you need to make sure of is that you are using the trait **HasApiTokens** in the **User Model:**

```
use Laravel\Sanctum\HasApiTokens;
 
class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use HasApiTokens;
}
```