# How to authorize request using laravel breeze?

Tags: laravel, axios, laravel-sanctum, laravel-breeze

I have installed laravel breeze with sail, and I'm trying to make axios request, like

```
axios.get('/api/messages');
```

But I got an error

```
{"message":"Unauthenticated."}
```

I am authorized, and can open pages like "dashboard".
I added

```
axios.defaults.withCredentials = true;
```

to my "bootstrap.js" but it didn't help.

Comment: show us a code logic in laravel to where does `'/api/messages'` route pointing at ?

Comment: how are you generating and passing tokens? also you can check my answer here on similar topic: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74936904/question-password-reset-token-in-laravel-breeze-inertia-react/74937043#74937043

Comment: I don't generate of pass tokens any way